# Hoi4 crashed with exit code 1(AstraLInux)

Tags: steam

When i try run hoi4 on launcher paradox thye give error:

ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Hearts of Iron IV/hoi4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Hearts of Iron IV/hoi4) /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Hearts of Iron IV/hoi4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version` GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Hearts of Iron IV/hoi4)

Can you help me please?

I try delete some file in .local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
but
it didn't work